# Remote node.js http server doesnt start or fails to listen

Tags: node.js, debian

I ran some node.js tests on my windows machine and everything worked well. Now I installed node on my debian remote machine, and Im trying to run a simple http server:

```
var http = require("http");

http.createServer(function(request, response) {
  response.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "text/plain"});
  response.write("Hello World");
  response.end();
}).listen(8888);
```

I execute using SSH: `node server.js` Now when I go to my server ip http://xxx.xxx.22.127:8888 the server times out.

What am I doing wrong? I tested with some simpler scripts and node.js appears to be installed properly. Can it be a firewall issue, or maybe I should add a host-ip or sommit?

Side question: when I run `node server.js` in putty i cant type anymore, how do I return to the commandline? :)

EDIT: My iptables info

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target        prot opt source               destination
fail2ban-ssh  tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            multiport dports ssh
ACCEPT        tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            tcp dpt:5900
ACCEPT        tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            tcp dpt:8888

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain fail2ban-ssh (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
RETURN     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There may be a software firewall (`iptables` for instance) or a hardware firewall in place which is stopping requests to `8888` from being received. The only way to resolve this is to dig into your server configuration/ network architecture to track down the problem. For instance, you can use `iptables -L` if you're using iptables to see what rules are enforced currently.

There could also be another application already listening on `8888`, but I believe this throws an error rather than failing like this, so I doubt this is the problem. One way to check this would be via `netstat -a`.

*Needless to say, I am saying the code you've got should work fine, and it's a problem with your server set-up that is causing this.*

**Side answer:** Use [`nohup`](http://ss64.com/bash/nohup.html) and `&` like so; `nohup node server.js &`, although you should look at installing a module such as [`forever`](https://github.com/nodejitsu/forever/), and then use `forever start server.js`; `forever` has the additional benefit of restarting your node process automagically if it crashes.

Comment: My thoughts exactly. Deleted my answer and +1 to this one.

Comment: I checked to see if it was used already, now Ill check for the iptables. Im pretty much a noob with Debian, but Ill figure it out. Thanks for both the answer and the side answer

Comment: Ill update my post with iptables info. I already tweedled a bit with it before I came to bug you guys with my questions, thats why you see both port 5900 and 8888 mentioned... Still its not working tho

Comment: @HansWassink: I'll be the first to admit `iptables` aren't my strong point. You might find better luck asking this on http://serverfault.com, as it's no longer a programming question.

Comment: Well Ill go and fish this up, and will edit my answer when i find definite proof. thanks so far

Comment: There was a hardware firewall in the way... Solved the issue using a new topic on serverfault http://serverfault.com/questions/390046/my-node-js-http-server-appears-to-be-blocked-by-iptables

Comment: @HansWassink: Glad you got it sorted!

Answer (score 0):

> What am I doing wrong? I tested with some simpler scripts and node.js appears to be installed properly. Can it be a firewall issue, or maybe I should add a host-ip or sommit?

I see nothing wrong with the script itself. Try to debug it with `telnet`.

> Side question: when I run node server.js in putty i cant type anymore, how do I return to the commandline? :)

`node server.js &`

(also see `man nohup`)

Comment: I didnt say there as anything wrong with the script, it works on windows even. I just tried other simpler scripts, with just a console.log for example to see if the installation was correct.